# What is meant by "neighboring points"?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, variational-principle, geometry, geodesics

I have recently been frequently encountering the phrase "neighboring points" during my studies. For example:

> **Fermat's Principle.** Optical rays travelling between two points, $A$ and $B$, follow a path such that the time of travel (or the optical pathlength) between the two points is an extremum relative to neighboring paths.

(*Fundamentals of Photonics, 3rd edition*, by Teich and Saleh.)

> The curve along a surface which marks the shortest distance between two neighboring points is called a *geodesic* of the surface.

(*Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences*, by Boas.)

But what exactly is meant by "neighboring points"?

We all know what the colloquial definition of "neighboring points" is, but this definition does not seem to be useful in the context that physicists use it. The concept of "neighboring points" can also be defined rigorously (mathematically), but, if we use this definition, then, again, the way in which I see physicists using "neighboring points" would not be useful.

As someone who has just started encountering this phrase, I think a lot of my confusion with related concepts is related to it. After thinking about this, what I suspect is meant by "neighboring points" is that, if we have, say, the surface of a sphere, and we want to know the shortest distance between any two points (in other words, *neighboring points*, despite the fact that they are not "neighbors" in the colloquial sense) on the surface of the sphere, then, since these two points are located in the domain in question (the surface of the sphere), then they are defined as being "neighboring points"? Is this correct? If not, then what is the correct definition and understanding of "neighboring points"?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this concept.

Comment: Your first quote talks about neighbouring *paths*, not points, so it's a little different; it's a concept from [the calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations). Generally, neighbouring points are close enough that we can treat the neighbourhood as linear. Eg, 2 points on a sphere are neighbours if we can approximate their neighbourhood as flat.

Comment: @PM2Ring The second quote is from a chapter on Calculus of Variations, which I am reading to gain more insight on the first quote, which is in the context of Fermat's principle $\left( \delta \int_A^B n(\mathbf{r}) \ ds = 0  \right)$. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/512339/141502

Comment: @PM2Ring Your comment is insightful. So how would the fact that neighbouring points are points that are close enough that we can treat the neighbourhood as linear then relate to the concept of *neighboring paths*?

Comment: Ok. So you know in simple calculus that given a function $y=f(x)$ then $dy/dx=f'(x)=0$ gives us the minima, maxima, and points of inflexion of $f(x)$. Right? And that near an extrema the value of the function changes very slowly. The calculus of variations is based on the same principle: the paths which are near an extremal path have almost the same value (eg length) as the extremal  path does.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, that completely makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/512339/2451